# The internal and external bisectors of $\angle A$ meet line $BC$ at $E$ and $F$. Show that the tangent at $A$ to $\bigcirc ABC$ bisects $EF$.

Tags: geometry

> Suppose the internal and external bisector of $\angle A$ meet the side $BC$ (produced) at $E$ and $F$, respectively. If the tangent at $A$ to $\bigcirc ABC$ meets $BC$ (produced) at $D$, prove that $D$ bisects $EF$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker know about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or talking over your head. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Since comments are easily overlooked, [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3478483/edit) to add your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Simple angle chasing.

Note that $AEF$ is a right triangle, so to show that $D$ is the midpoint, it suffices to thow that $ADE$ is isosceles with $DA = DE$.

> We have $ \angle DEA = \frac{\alpha }{2} + \beta$ by exterior angle of triangle and $\angle DAE = \beta + \frac{\alpha}{2}$ by alternate segment theorem.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Note $\angle DAB = \angle ACD = \alpha $ due to tangent line AD. Then, $\angle DAE = \angle DEA = \alpha + \angle BAE$ because AE bisects $\angle BAC$. The triangle ADE is isosceles.

Also note that AE $\perp$ AF due to the angle bisectors AD and AE. Then, the triangle AFD is isosceles because of the isosceles triangle ADE. Thus, DE = DA = DF and D is the midpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Let $c>b$. Let $K$ be a midpoint of $EF$. We have $\frac{EC}{EB}=\frac{b}{c}$, $\frac{FC}{FB}=\frac{b}{c}$, $EC+EB=a$, $FB-FC=a$. Then $EC=\frac{ab}{b+c}$, $EB=\frac{ac}{b+c}$, $FC=\frac{ab}{c-b}$. Then $EF=EC+FC=\frac{2abc}{c^2-b^2}$. Since $AK$ is median of triange $AEF$ with $\angle EAF=\frac{\pi}{2}$ then $AK=\frac{1}{2}EF$. Then $AK=\frac{abc}{c^2-b^2}$. Also we have $KC=KE-EC=\frac{ab^2}{c^2-b^2}$, $KB=KE+EB=\frac{ac^2}{c^2-b^2}$. Since $KC=\frac{ab^2}{c^2-b^2}$, $KB=\frac{ac^2}{c^2-b^2}$ and $AK=\frac{abc}{c^2-b^2}$ then easy to see that $KA^2=KC \cdot KB$. Since $KA^2=KC \cdot KB$ then $AK$ is tangent at $A$ to the circumcircle of triangle $ABC$. Then $K=D$. Then $D$ is midpoint of $EF$.